# Modified HttpServletResponse in custom filter gets truncated to original response length

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlets

I have created a custom filter which modifies the content of an http response. The content replacement itself works ok, however when the content size is larger than the original response, it gets truncated to the same size as the original one whilst missing the remaining characters.

This is my custom filter:

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String actionHeader = request.getHeader(RestApi.ACTION_HEADER_NAME);
    if (actionHeader != null) {
        String contentTypeValue = ContentTypeMap.getContentType(actionHeader);
        if (contentTypeValue != null) { 
            try {
                response.setHeader(RestApi.ACTION_HEADER_NAME, "TRUE");
                log.debug("New Action - Action request detected: " + request.getRequestURL());
                ActionRequestWrapper actionRequest = new ActionRequestWrapper(request, contentTypeValue);
                ActionResponseWrapper actionResponse = new ActionResponseWrapper(response);

                performActionRequest(actionRequest);

                filterChain.doFilter(actionRequest, actionResponse);

                byte[] originalResponseBody = actionResponse.getResponseData();
                byte[] updatedBody = performAction(originalResponseBody);
                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                os.write(updatedBody);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("New Action - An error occurred while trying to perform action",e);
            }
        }
        else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
    else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my ResponseWrapper:

```
public class ActionResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

private final ByteArrayOutputStream capture;
private ServletOutputStream output;
private PrintWriter writer;

public ActionResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException {
    super(response);
    capture = new ByteArrayOutputStream(response.getBufferSize());
}

@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    if (writer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    if (output == null) {
        output = new ServletOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                capture.write(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {
                capture.flush();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                capture.close();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setWriteListener(WriteListener arg0) {
            }
        };
    }

    return output;
}

@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
    if (output != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    if (writer == null) {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(capture, getCharacterEncoding()));
    }

    return writer;
}

@Override
public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
    super.flushBuffer();

    if (writer != null) {
        writer.flush();
    } else if (output != null) {
        output.flush();
    }
}

public byte[] getResponseData() throws IOException {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    } else if (output != null) {
        output.close();
    }
    return capture.toByteArray();
}
}
```

This is my RequestWrapper:

```
public class ActionRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private final String contentTypeValue;
private final String contentLengthValue;
private byte[] body;

public ActionRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String contentType) throws IOException{
    super(request);
    contentTypeValue = contentType;
    StringBuilder _body = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader()) {
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            _body.append(line);
    }
    this.body = _body.toString().getBytes();
    contentLengthValue = String.valueOf(body.length);
}

@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME)) {
        return contentTypeValue;
    }
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_NAME)) {
        return contentLengthValue;
    }
    return super.getHeader(name);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String headerName) {
    if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME)) {
        return Collections.enumeration(Collections.singletonList(contentTypeValue));
    }
    else if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_NAME)) {
        return Collections.enumeration(Collections.singletonList(contentLengthValue));
    }
    return super.getHeaders(headerName);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames(){
    Enumeration<String> original = super.getHeaderNames();
    List<String> newHeaders = new ArrayList<String>(){
        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o){
            String paramStr = (String)o;
            for (String headerName : this){
                if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase(paramStr)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    newHeaders.addAll(Collections.list(original));

    if (!newHeaders.contains(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME)){
        newHeaders.add(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME);
    }
    if (!newHeaders.contains(CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_NAME)){
        newHeaders.add(CONTENT_LENGTH_HEADER_NAME);
    }
    return Collections.enumeration(newHeaders);
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);
    return new ServletInputStream() {
        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return byteArrayInputStream.available() > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {

        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}

public byte[] getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(byte[] body) {
    this.body = body;
}
}
```

I have created a filter registration class as well where I have registered my filter beans and configured their order. Everything works fine except for the fact that the updated body of my response is truncated to the number of bytes my original response had.

I was able to make this work using `ControllerAdvice` and `ResponseBodyAdvice` but since I prefer using the filter, what I want to know is why is my updated response body getting truncated, and is it possible to fix this using filters? I have a feeling this has to do with me upgrading from `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-*-8.5.4` to `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-*-8.5.20` but if this is indeed the case I want to know what changed?
I am using `Spring Boot Version 1.5.7`.

Appreciate the help!

**UPDATE:**
Using `ControllerAdvice` and `ResponseBodyAdvice` makes my solution much more complicated since my body is not necessarily a String, and defining my body as an Object will require too much modification to my current existing code. After digging a little deeper I found that the `Content-Length` header in the `Http11Processor` class from `package org.apache.coyote.http11` is set to the size of the original response right before the response commit and that is why my new response is getting truncated:

**Http11Processor.java:**

```
@Override
protected final void prepareResponse() throws IOException {

    boolean entityBody = true;
    contentDelimitation = false;

    OutputFilter[] outputFilters = outputBuffer.getFilters();

    if (http09 == true) {
        // HTTP/0.9
        outputBuffer.addActiveFilter(outputFilters[Constants.IDENTITY_FILTER]);
        outputBuffer.commit();
        return;
    }

    int statusCode = response.getStatus();
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode == 204 || statusCode == 205 ||
            statusCode == 304) {
        // No entity body
        outputBuffer.addActiveFilter
            (outputFilters[Constants.VOID_FILTER]);
        entityBody = false;
        contentDelimitation = true;
        if (statusCode == 205) {
            // RFC 7231 requires the server to explicitly signal an empty
            // response in this case
            response.setContentLength(0);
        } else {
            response.setContentLength(-1);
        }
    }

    MessageBytes methodMB = request.method();
    if (methodMB.equals("HEAD")) {
        // No entity body
        outputBuffer.addActiveFilter
            (outputFilters[Constants.VOID_FILTER]);
        contentDelimitation = true;
    }

    // Sendfile support
    if (endpoint.getUseSendfile()) {
        prepareSendfile(outputFilters);
    }

    // Check for compression
    boolean isCompressible = false;
    boolean useCompression = false;
    if (entityBody && (compressionLevel > 0) && sendfileData == null) {
        isCompressible = isCompressible();
        if (isCompressible) {
            useCompression = useCompression();
        }
        // Change content-length to -1 to force chunking
        if (useCompression) {
            response.setContentLength(-1);
        }
    }

    MimeHeaders headers = response.getMimeHeaders();
    // A SC_NO_CONTENT response may include entity headers
    if (entityBody || statusCode == HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT) {
        String contentType = response.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null) {
            headers.setValue("Content-Type").setString(contentType);
        }
        String contentLanguage = response.getContentLanguage();
        if (contentLanguage != null) {
            headers.setValue("Content-Language")
                .setString(contentLanguage);
        }
    }

    long contentLength = response.getContentLengthLong();
    boolean connectionClosePresent = false;
    if (contentLength != -1) {
        headers.setValue("Content-Length").setLong(contentLength);
        outputBuffer.addActiveFilter
            (outputFilters[Constants.IDENTITY_FILTER]);
        contentDelimitation = true;
    } else {
        // If the response code supports an entity body and we're on
        // HTTP 1.1 then we chunk unless we have a Connection: close header
        connectionClosePresent = isConnectionClose(headers);
        if (entityBody && http11 && !connectionClosePresent) {
            outputBuffer.addActiveFilter
                (outputFilters[Constants.CHUNKED_FILTER]);
            contentDelimitation = true;
            headers.addValue(Constants.TRANSFERENCODING).setString(Constants.CHUNKED);
        } else {
            outputBuffer.addActiveFilter
                (outputFilters[Constants.IDENTITY_FILTER]);
        }
    }

    if (useCompression) {
        outputBuffer.addActiveFilter(outputFilters[Constants.GZIP_FILTER]);
        headers.setValue("Content-Encoding").setString("gzip");
    }
    // If it might be compressed, set the Vary header
    if (isCompressible) {
        // Make Proxies happy via Vary (from mod_deflate)
        MessageBytes vary = headers.getValue("Vary");
        if (vary == null) {
            // Add a new Vary header
            headers.setValue("Vary").setString("Accept-Encoding");
        } else if (vary.equals("*")) {
            // No action required
        } else {
            // Merge into current header
            headers.setValue("Vary").setString(
                    vary.getString() + ",Accept-Encoding");
        }
    }

    // Add date header unless application has already set one (e.g. in a
    // Caching Filter)
    if (headers.getValue("Date") == null) {
        headers.addValue("Date").setString(
                FastHttpDateFormat.getCurrentDate());
    }

    // FIXME: Add transfer encoding header

    if ((entityBody) && (!contentDelimitation)) {
        // Mark as close the connection after the request, and add the
        // connection: close header
        keepAlive = false;
    }

    // This may disabled keep-alive to check before working out the
    // Connection header.
    checkExpectationAndResponseStatus();

    // If we know that the request is bad this early, add the
    // Connection: close header.
    if (keepAlive && statusDropsConnection(statusCode)) {
        keepAlive = false;
    }
    if (!keepAlive) {
        // Avoid adding the close header twice
        if (!connectionClosePresent) {
            headers.addValue(Constants.CONNECTION).setString(
                    Constants.CLOSE);
        }
    } else if (!http11 && !getErrorState().isError()) {
        headers.addValue(Constants.CONNECTION).setString(Constants.KEEPALIVE);
    }

    // Add server header
    if (server == null) {
        if (serverRemoveAppProvidedValues) {
            headers.removeHeader("server");
        }
    } else {
        // server always overrides anything the app might set
        headers.setValue("Server").setString(server);
    }

    // Build the response header
    try {
        outputBuffer.sendStatus();

        int size = headers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            outputBuffer.sendHeader(headers.getName(i), headers.getValue(i));
        }
        outputBuffer.endHeaders();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(t);
        // If something goes wrong, reset the header buffer so the error
        // response can be written instead.
        outputBuffer.resetHeaderBuffer();
        throw t;
    }

    outputBuffer.commit();
}
```

Is there a way I can somehow change the value of the `Content-Length` header to the length of my new response?

Comment: did you find an answer to this @dabadie

Answer (score 0):

In your `ActionResponseWrapper` change the following line

```
capture = new ByteArrayOutputStream(response.getBufferSize());
```

to

```
capture = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Because by providing the size to `ByteArrayOutputStream` you are restricting its size to original Response content length. Because of this `ActionResponseWrapper.getResponseData` will return only up to original response length.

Comment: Hi shazin, thanks for your response, however I tried this but my updated response still gets truncated to the size of my original response.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
actionResponse.reset();

os.flush(); 
os.write(updatedBody); 
os.close();
```

Then it won't truncate anymore.

Comment: Where would be the appropriate place to put this line?

Comment: The right order should be:
actionResponse.reset();
os.flush();
os.write(updatedBody);
os.close();